# Showing $\mathrm{PSL}(2,q)$ is perfect

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, permutations, finite-fields

Let $G = \mathrm{PSL}(2,q)$ be given as permutation group on $\Omega = \mathbb{F}_q \cup \{\infty\}$, where $q = p^n$ is a prime power. $G$ is generated by translations $\alpha_t \colon x \mapsto x+t$ ($t \in \mathbb{F}_q$), multiplications with squares $\beta_k \colon x \mapsto k^2 x$ ($k \in \mathbb{F}_q^\times$), and by $\gamma \colon x \mapsto -x^{-1}$. I am looking for a direct proof that $\mathrm{PSL}(2,q)$ is perfect for $q > 3$, i.e. G' = G.

**My attempt:** If $q>3$ then any translation $\alpha_t$ is a commutator, so $G'$ contains the subgroup $P \leq G$ of all translations (which is also a $p$-Sylow subgroup of $G$). Hence $U := \langle P^g : g \in G \rangle \leq G'$. It suffices to show $U=G$. Simple calculations show that $U$ has at least $q^2$ elements, and that $U$ is 2-transitive on $\Omega$. In particular, $G = U \langle \beta_k \rangle$, where $k \in \mathbb{F}_q^\times$ is primitive, so it suffices to show $\beta_k \in U$.

I would be happy about any hint how to proceed. Different attempts are appreciated as well.

Comment: I am aware that even $\mathrm{SL}(n,q)$ is perfect for $n>2$ or $q>3$ but I want to avoid matrices here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know you said that you wanted to avoid matrices, but frankly that seems silly, especially given that the definition of ${\rm PSL}(2,q)$ involves matrices. Why tie your hands behind your back?

It is easier to show that $G = {\rm SL}(2,q)$ is generated by its Sylow $p$-subgroups than to do the same directly for ${\rm PSL}(2,q)$. So for $g \in G$ we want to show that $G$ is a product of elements of order $p$.

Now $G$ acts on a $2$-dimensional vectors space $V$ over ${\mathbb F}_q$. Let $v \in V$. Since not every $p$-element fixes the subspace generated by $v$, by multiplying $g$ by a $p$-element if necessary, we may assume that $v$ and $u=gv$ are linearly independent.

Now there is s $p$-element $h$ with $h(v-u) = v-u$ and $hu = u + (v-u) = v$, and so $hgv = v$ and, since $hg$ has determinant $1$, it must be $p$-element, and we are done.

Note that one part of the more general proof that ${\rm SL}(n,q)$ is perfect is to show that it is generated by transvections, and that is what we have done here.

Comment: How do you conclude from $hgv=v$ that $hg$ is a $p$-element? Besides, I don't see you using matrices either. :) It seems to me that your whole argument is equally valid in PSL - I just don't understand the final conclusion.

Comment: The stabilizer of a vector in ${\rm SL}(2,q)$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup, and the easiest way to see that is that its elements are upper unitriangular matrices wrt a suitable basis. But the reason I prefer to work in ${\rm SL}(2,q)$ is that the argument involves actions on vectors rather than the projective action on $1$-dimensional subspaces.

Comment: I see, this is the big difference to PSL: there the point stabilizers are not Sylow subgroups, so probably your argument cannot be adopted for PSL. Thanks for your answer! I will accept it if no further answers occur within some days. Btw: I prefer to work in PSL(2,q) not because of its action on 1-dimensional subspaces, but on $\mathbb{F}_q \cup \{\infty\}$. I find it very convenient to work with those permutations (much more than with matrices).